# Go - How can I check for type equality?

Tags: go

Say I have the following code:

```
var x interface{}
y := 4
x = y
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(x))
```

This will print int as the type. My question is how can I test for the type? I know there is the type switch which does this, so I could do:

```
switch x.(type) {
case int:
    fmt.Println("This is an int")
}
```

But if I only want to check for just one specific type the switch seems like the wrong tool. Is there a more direct method of doing this like

```
reflect.TypeOf(x) == int
```

or is the type switch the way to go?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Type assertions return two values .. the first is the converted value, the second is a bool indicating if the type assertion worked properly.

So you could do this:

```
_, ok := x.(int)

if ok {
    fmt.Println("Its an int")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Its NOT an int")
}
```

..or, shorthand:

```
if _, ok := x.(int); ok {
    fmt.Println("Its an int")
}
```

<kbd>[See it in the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/OXr2yu8FnV)</kbd>

Comment: Tks! Came up with the same answer at the same time myself :)

Answer (score 4):

I just figured out another way of doing this based on [this](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
if _, ok := x.(int); ok {
    fmt.Println("This is an int")
}
```

Comment: this will work fine if you need  a specific type. If you want to decide between  many types, a type switch is of course better.

Comment: Ahh.. you must have already answered just as I did. Oh well, glad you found your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch) you can find a really simple example of what you're trying to achieve.

```
var t interface{}
t = functionOfSomeType()

switch t := t.(type) {
default:
    fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T", t)       // %T prints whatever type t has
case bool:
    fmt.Printf("boolean %t\n", t)             // t has type bool
case int:
    fmt.Printf("integer %d\n", t)             // t has type int
case *bool:
    fmt.Printf("pointer to boolean %t\n", *t) // t has type *bool
case *int:
    fmt.Printf("pointer to integer %d\n", *t) // t has type *int
}
```

If you have a single type that you have to check, use a simple **if**, otherwise use a switch for better readability.

Comment: As per policy, please copy the relevant part of the linked document into your answer.